# Error showing as Extra argument 'eventDispatcher' in call while running react-native app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, xcode13

I am using expo-modules-core ("expo-modules-core": "^0.9.2").
I have tried npm install and pod install from my terminal and dependencies are successfully installed.
Then I tried to run the app with Xcode 13.0 with the iOS15.0 simulator but I am getting the following error and it becomes build failed.

**node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/Views/ComponentData.swift:22:84: Extra argument 'eventDispatcher' in call**

The error showing in the following method inside the file (node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios/Swift/Views/**ComponentData.swift**).

```
public init(viewModule: ViewModuleWrapper, managerClass: ViewModuleWrapper.Type, bridge: RCTBridge) {
self.moduleHolder = viewModule.wrappedModuleHolder
super.init(managerClass: managerClass, bridge: bridge, eventDispatcher: bridge.eventDispatcher())
}
```

Could you help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We can fix this issue by downgrading `"expo-modules-core": "~0.6.4",`